# Type generic that given a type of an object and a field returns the type of the field

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am new to typescript, so for the needs of my project I need to create function that given an field of an object and returns among other attributes the type of that object field.

In plain javascript this would be something like:

```
type myObjectType = {
   field1:string,
   field2: number
}
```

```
const myObject:myObjectType{
   field1:'string',
   field2: 0
}

const generateMyElement = (field) => {
   attr1:val1,
   attr2:val2,
   attr3:myObject['field']
}
```

I would like to type this function however I am not able to do it correctly.

I have tried this:

```
type generateMyElement = (
  name: keyof myObjectType,
) => {
  attr1:string,
  attr2:string,
  value:myObjectType[name]
}
```

however I cannot mix argument names with typescript. What should be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Could you had an example of what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function.

```
type MyObjectType = {
    field1: string,
    field2: number
}

const myObject: MyObjectType = {
    field1: 'string',
    field2: 0
}

function generateMyElement<K extends keyof MyObjectType>(field: K): {
    attr1: string,
    attr2: string,
    attr3: MyObjectType[K]
} {
    return {
        attr1: 'val1',
        attr2: 'val2',
        attr3: myObject[field]
    }
}
```

- This creates a function with a generic type parameter `K`.
- `K` must `extend` (or be a subtype of) `keyof MyObjectType`, which means that it must be one of the keys that that type.
- The type of `K` is determined by what is passed to `field`.
- The return type is then an object type where `attr3` is the type of whatever the `K` property of `MyObjectType` is.

Then to use that:

```
const testA = generateMyElement('field1').attr3 // string
const testB = generateMyElement('field2').attr3 // number
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsAKuaBeKA3gLABQU5UAZgJYQA2AJgIwBcUAzsAE7UB2A5gBpSFKrUYAmNrwCuAW0QQupAL6lSaAPa9OUOQhTpgbOElQZskKPmJkKNeszYByTjwHPhd8g8lsADKrqJJQyvBjU2lD8ELxKAIbAEHAAonQQcrHAADwA0lAQAB5JvAzsUADWECCalLAG5lg4AHwAFL4MbLkAlGy2ooncrBzcfEIiFINcUiPu495QUwDMJg1GlhAA2rkAuqqEE+RcEMAyXLwHCwPAQy4AbvF0TJ6Hoos30-ePEi9Xkx8rPRrDCbDp7BZqEiQjTaXRJTgAQWs0ViCSSqXSmV4wFazg6z26ADplqQAPSk0QAPQA-MEtDpgFB4cAAELImJxLiJZIgNIZLK4jo-Ikkkjkqm0khAA)

---

> Also, how I can "export" it to a type?

The type of the above function would be:

```
type RegisterFN = <K extends keyof MyObjectType>(field: K) => {
    attr1: string;
    attr2: string;
    attr3: MyObjectType[K];
}
```

Note how the generic type parameter is on the *right* side of the `=` operator. This is the type for a generic *function*, and it is *not* a generic *type*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524136/how-to-define-a-generic-function-type-in-typescript-two-similar-ways) for a description of the difference.

You can now do this:

```
const generateMyElement: RegisterFN = (field) =>{
    return {
        attr1: 'val1',
        attr2: 'val2',
        attr3: myObject[field]
    }
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsAKuaBeKA3gLABQU5UAZgJYQA2AJgIwBcUAzsAE7UB2A5gBpSFKrUYAmNrwCuAW0QQupAL6lSaAPa9OUOQhTpgbOElQZskKPmJkKNeszYByTjwHPhd8g8lsADKrqJKBWAEoQ-NScSgBiAHLWUAA8ANJQEAAewBC8DOxQANYQIJqUsAbmWDgAfAAUvgxsqQCU1jWEIhQAhsDcrBzcfPwA3F3kvdxSg+6j41CTXADMJpVGlhAA2qkAumMkaiQa2rr8uUq9EHAAonQQcrnGUBFRMVwJSQ3iDG24NbaiLgQYAyLi8TreUQLPpcAbOABu3ToTE881Ei2mCKRElRkPRMJWejWGE2jR280Oh2OOmAUBynAAgkkzrwLjkbncHrxgHVnI0US0AHSLJakAD0YtEAD0APzBLQ0ukQTgAIWZ5y4lw590evMaOKFIvFkoostIQA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. How is K evaluated since you don't pass it as type argument?

Comment: Also, how I can "export" it to a type? Eg I tried
`type registerFN<K extends keyof MyObjectType> = (field:K) => Record<string,any>` but when I try something like this
`const generateMyElement:registerFN<> = (field) =>{
    return {
        attr1: 'val1',
        attr2: 'val2',
        attr3: myObject[field]
    }
}` I get multiple errors [link](http://shorturl.at/kmpBJ)

Comment: `K` gets it's value from `(field: K)`, so whatever type you pass as the argument `field`, is the type of `K`.

Comment: As for your other question, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you once more for the explanatation and your answer!